# MSDN like application on SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, performance, architecture

I have a project initiated for a client where they want a Knowledge Base Application for their line of business. The interface needed is almost a replica of MSDN Library which needs to implemented over SharePoint 2010.

They have a very large dataset of around 100k Questions and Solutions with well defined taxonomies.

My question currently pertains to the design of the application in the context performance management.

If I want to implement a solution of this scale like MSDN on SharePoint, what are the high level items I need to consider to create a design that adhere to the fast load of application pages in the browser and ensure optimum load(CPU,RAM) on WFEs and Database servers.

The capacity planning for hardware is already covered. I just need someone good pointers for the development and architecture of the above.

Comment: When you say a replica of the MSDN Library, do you mean the class library references too? Because, in my opinion, I wouldn't host those in SharePoint. I would use a custom ASP.NET templated content app for this - because the entirety of the class libraries on MSDN are based on XML documentation produced by visual studio - it's far easier to template this via Razor or something similar rather than with SharePoint's Publishing capabilities. Also, it'll be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article to from Microsoft for reference:
[SharePoint Server 2010 capacity management: Software boundaries and limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx)

*This article describes software boundaries and limits of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010. These include the following:
Boundaries: Static limits that cannot be exceeded by design
Thresholds: Configurable limits that can be exceeded to accommodate specific requirements
Supported limits: Configurable limits that have been set by default to a tested value*

Answer (score 0):

Sure! I believe you site is probably a How-To or FAQ's site. So Search and Navigation is what you need to focus on.

Because as you reckon it is going to be another MSDN, Stackexchange etc, I would say following are things where you need to focus on,

Search is key for retrieving existing records. Please plan for the search either OOTB or FAST.

Navigation is really important because users must be able to navigate along, troll around and find or access stuffs easily.

Also, Information Architecture(IA) and governance is really really important.

Who owns and maintains those data's? Who is responsible to remove and add new stuffs.

This [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262900.aspx) is a good place to start with.

There are tonnes of site out there, which are FAQ based so these should help you get started and steer you in the right direction!

Cheers!